# Unresolved compilation problems: The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. Implicit constructor Object() is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I created a Java class in Eclipse Java EE IDE (Luna Release 2 (4.4.2) and Java jre1.8.0_66.

```
package com.luv2code.jsf.hello;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;



 @ManagedBean
 public class Student {


     private String sfirstName;
     private String slastName;

     // create a no-arg constructor
     public Student() {

     }

     public String getFirstName() {
         return sfirstName;
     }

     public void setFirstName(String sfirstName) {
         this.sfirstName = sfirstName;
     }

     public String getLastName() {
         return slastName;
     }

     public void setLastName(String slastName) {
         this.slastName = slastName;
     }

     // define public getter and setter methods to expose properties of the managed Bean

 }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
HTTP Status 500- Unresolved compilation problems
type Exception report
message unresolved compilation problem
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type

 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 String cannot be resolved to a type

 com.luv2code.jsf.hello.Student.<init>(Student.java:1)r





com.luv2code.jsf.hello.Student.<init>(Student.java:1)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
 com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
 com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
 com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
 com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
 org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
 org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
 org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
 com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
 javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
 javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
 javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
 javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
 javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
 com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
 com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

and if I hover over String I see

> String cannot be resolved to a type

and if I hover over `Student` (the no-arg constructor) I see:

> Implicit constructor Object() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.

I am not sure why it wont let me use the private String in m Student class.
Can anyone explain this or offer me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend to read a tutorial on JSF. because you seem to have problem in the basics of JSF!

now back to your Problems:

1. Student class should be a DataModel class and not a managedBean class
2. depending on your configurations of the FacesServlet pattern in web.xml, you should run the application and not a single file. after starting the Container(Tomcat), call the url to your Project: i.e localhost:8080/Testing/faces/test.xhtml
3. in your xhtml you have a syntax error: `<:inputText value="#{student.slastName}" />`, its should start with `<h:...`
4. a managedbean should have a scope(applicationScoped, SessionScoped, ViewScoped, ...etc) you don't declare this in your bean
5. private fields of a managedBean should have getter/setter, only public can be accessed from outside(within the view/xhtml)

here an example how it should be:

**DataModel class:**

```
package a.b.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7013884476678061379L;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student() {

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }    
}
```

**ManagedBean:**

```
package a.b.controler;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import a.b.model.Student;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class StudentManager implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6254452297683880945L;
    private Student student;    
    public StudentManager(){

    }   
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Called once on Object init!");
        this.student = new Student();
    }
    public final void save (AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        System.out.println("Ajax command ....");
        System.out.println("Firstname: "+this.getStudent().getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Lasttname: "+this.getStudent().getLastName());
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Testing</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

the View **test.xhtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Student Registration</title>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form>
             First Name: <h:inputText value="#{studentManager.student.firstName}" />
        <br />
        <br />
             Last Name: <h:inputText value="#{studentManager.student.lastName}" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{studentManager.save}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

after starting the Container(Tomcat), open it in the browser this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/Testing/faces/test.xhtml
```

Comment: Did you read the errors OP got? None of that all is related to JSF. OP just completely messed up the IDE configuration. I edited the question to reduce irrelevant noise so it's better focused.